# Cordova InAppBrowser Loading Spinner for Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I've an app built with cordova and InAppBrowser. I'm trying to show a "loading spinner" in every page.
In iOS it's working well on every page I load, but Android fails.
On iOS I just edited `self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]` this line in CDVInappBrowser.m and works.
Does Android have a similar feature ?

Here is my code:

```
       // Cordova is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {

            var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_blank", "location=no", "toolbar=no", "closebuttoncaption=a", "EnableViewPortScale=no");

            navigator.notification.activityStart("Loading", "Loading...");
            setTimeout(function(){
                navigator.notification.activityStop();
            }, 5000);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin:
https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog

Working for me in Android. You should use this method to show a spinner with title and message:

```
window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show("Loading","Loading...");
```

Your code would be:

```
  function onDeviceReady() {

        var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_blank", "location=no", "toolbar=no", "closebuttoncaption=a", "EnableViewPortScale=no");

        window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show("Loading","Loading...");
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide();
        }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: Great solution! Worked well for me!

Comment: Honestly that's not the good solution because you never know how long it would take for a page to finish loading. Here is used 5 seconds with `setTimeout`. I don't say that this method doesn't work but it is not good.

Comment: The solution is use the plugin mentioned and invoke it as It said. The code is just adapt it to the scenario that vbotio exposes. Indeed, It doesn't really make sense use  `setTimeout` to me either

Answer (score 0):

**Resvolvi dessa forma**

//window.open Example

```
 // Wait for device API libraries to load
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   function onDeviceReady() {
    // external url
   // var ref = window.open(encodeURI('http://mfsom.com.br/'), '_blank', 'location=no','toolbar=no');
   //relative document
     ref = window.open('http://mfsom.com.br/','_self',',location=no');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstartCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', loadstopCallback);
ref.addEventListener('loadloaderror', loaderrorCallback);
ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);

function loadstartCallback(event) {

    showSpinnerDialog();

}

function loadstopCallback(event) {
    hideSpinnerDialog();
}

function loaderrorCallback(error) {
console.log('Erro ao carregar: ' + error.message)

}

function exitCallback() {
console.log('O navegador está fechado...')

}

function showSpinnerDialog() {
navigator.notification.activityStart("Carregando..");
//$.mobile.loading("show");
}

function hideSpinnerDialog() {
navigator.notification.activityStop();
    //$.mobile.loading("hide");
}

// Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

// TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
```

};

Answer (score 0):

As both the answers here use the `activityStop()` which is deprecated, use your own spinner which you use in your app to prevent `InAppBrowser`'s blank opening screen

Open the `InAppBrowser` in using `hidden=yes` option and later in `loadstop` event listener show the `InAppBrowser`. Till then you can show your custom loader

```
var ref = window.open("http://m.estadao.com.br/?load-all=true", "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,closebuttoncaption=a,EnableViewPortScale=no,hidden=yes");
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
  showLoader();//`showLoader()` is your own loader function to show loader within your app
});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
  ref.show();
  hideLoader();//`hideLoader()` is your own loader function to hide loader within your app
});
```